# Force apt-get update to return success

Tags: ubuntu, bash, ubuntu-12.04, apt-get

I'm working with a system that invokes `apt-get update` from a Ruby Capistrano recipe.  Capistrano cares (apparently) about the return code of the shell commands it executes.  `apt-get update` is running into some missing urls (because the mirror I'm pointing to is incomplete), and when it finishes with a failure code, Capistrano stops processing the rest of the recipe.  I need `apt-get update` to ignore the missing urls and let Capistrano at least try to go on with its life.  I would have thought that `apt-get --force-yes -y --ignore-missing update` would have done it, but it didn't.  Am I missing the right incantation to get `apt-get` to do what I want, or am I stuck with either surrounding it with some shell hackery to mask the errors or figuring out why the mirror is incomplete in the first place?

Comment: If you want it always have a return value of success, why not use `apt-get update; true`?

Comment: Uh, right, yes, that would work.  Although I'm still curious as to whether apt-get itself provides a mechanism to achieve this.